# Code flow using startActivityForResult()

Tags: android, start-activity

I'm working on an Android app. I have an Activity that checks to see if an XML file exists on my device. If it doesn't exist, I call a routine that does a bunch of stuff, including downloading that file from a URL.

If it does exist, I want to prompt (Yes/No) the user to see if they want to re-download the file, or just skip it.

I started by using a Dialog. The discussions I saw said that Dialogs are only asynchronous, so I switched to using an Activity to prompt for Yes/No.

After further reading, I believe the real answer is that starting an Activity using `startActivity()` sets off the Activity asynchronously, but using `startActivityForResult()` sets it off synchronously (blocking). Is this statement correct?

OK, assuming my statement above is correct, I have been looking into how to get back to my original starting point in the code flow, knowing which button (Yes/No) was selected by the user.

All of the examples show me that I need to get my result using this.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {

}
```

I am struggling with how to put this into my code so that it flows easier. I see plenty of examples that show the pieces of code needed, but I'm not clear on how it all fits together. Does my code structure end up like this:

```
public class MainScreen extends Activity    {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    protected void onButtonClick(parameters)    {
        /* Do some work to see if the file exists */
        if (!file.exists()) {
            runComplexRoutine(various_parameters);

        } else {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PromptingActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("filename", variable_holding_filename);   // Just passing a parameter to use in the title of the caled Activity
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
                        // Point A
        }
    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {
        if (resultsCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)  {
            runComplexRoutine(various_parameters);
        }
        // else, do nothing...
    }

}
```

My problem with this is that I have to pass lots of `various_parameters` around. It would be great if I could resume flow at `Point A`, but that doesn't seem possible. Am I correct here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startActivityForResult()` is asynchronous. It can feel synchronous to the user since the UI will change and your calling activity will be paused (your `onPause()` method will be called).

Your calling activity however is still able to run code; you'll implement a callback to be called when the activity you started for result is completed (which makes it quite like a dialog).

Comment: I see what you are saying in the first statement. In the second statement, am I limited to returning to the `onActivityResult()` routine, or can I return to the point where I left (right after `startActivityForResult()`)? My concern is that I have quite a few parameters that would need to be passed to the called Activity, then back to the calling routine.

Comment: And, can you point me to a "complete" example, rather than ones that jsut show the pieces? Thanks!!!

Comment: When your activity calls `startActivityForResult()` your code will not block, so you have no way to return to the point where you left off. I think you're thinking of linear programming though, which really is not the way UI development works... you need to think more event-driven. Some event (`onCreate()`, perhaps) caused your code to run. Your event processing function will run to completion before you can receive another event (such as the result of your child activity).

Comment: http://joshhendo.blogspot.com/2011/04/android-using-startactivityforresult.html has an example. Take notice of the call to `setResult()` in the child activity, and `onActivityResult()` in the parent to receive results. Note also that you can pass a Bundle in the intent as an extra to give the child its parameters, and the child can set a Bundle as its result to pass back data.

Comment: I agree about the "linear thinking" comment. Most of my exerience is with .NET and PHP.  :-)  I'll look at that example. Thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found that using `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult` will move flow after `startActivityForResult` to `onActivityResult` and break flow of `startActivityForResult`. I thought about how to continue flow after `startActivityForResult` without breaking it. While thinking about appropriate method, I finally found the content of **"Getting a result from an activity"**. Hope this helps.

**Here's [a link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)!**